# What's a fallback for setting location.hash in IE when you've lost internet connection?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.location

In IE, if you lose internet connection or are in offline mode, and you try to set location.hash like this:

```
location.hash = '#anythinghere'
```

It throws an "Unspecified error".  Is there a way to know beforehand if setting location.hash will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what IE versions you need to support, you can check `navigator.onLine` to see if the browser thinks it's online or not.

Otherwise, try wrapping it in a `try{}`/`catch(){}` block.

Comment: Thanks this is awesome for IE8+ which happened to be just what I needed right now.